# Masking of Certain user specific data in Hybris

Tags: database, oracle, sap-commerce-cloud, data-masking, backoffice

We have a requirement, wherein we need to mask the user data like email id at database level in Hybris. Let us know the ideal approach of how the masking activity can be done in Hybris.

-Do we need to mask the data in backoffice seperately and hac seperately ?
-Can we directly mask the data in database without any impact in website and administrative console.?

Whether masking of data directly in database is a ideal approach or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mask it in DB, application also getting it as masked. So application can't send email. I think you can hide these fields with user authorization. If you want to show them as ***, you can use populator.

On the other hand, hybris updated versions has GDPR capability, it has these functionality. Check your version and documents.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box Hybris applies very elementary String manipulation for masking credit card numbers.
You can check-

```
de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.customer.impl.DefaultCustomerAccountService#getMaskedCardNumber()
```